# Замена имени с abc01 на abc1

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день! Есть вот такой селект. Есть репорт в котором юзер выбирает @Equipment из выпадающего спипска `KDF*`

Но в базе они хранятся в ячейке MACHINE в формате: `KDF0*`
Соответсвенно то, что я сделал спомощью CASE, не помогает. и это очевидно. 
Данных не будет, т.к CASE сработает уже в самом селект, и переименнует уже сам столбец.

Как поправить? Думал через REPLACE, но не особо понял как он работает с пропусками

```
DECLARE @Equipment varchar(50) 
SELECT  
        ID = Parm.ID,
        BrandName = Phys.PRODUCT,
        Value = Phys.MEAN,
        datetime = Phys.DATETIME,
        KDF =  CASE 
                        WHEN MACHINE = 'KDF04'
                        THEN  'KDF4'
                        WHEN MACHINE = 'KDF03'
                        THEN 'KDF3'
                        WHEN MACHINE = 'KDF02'
                        THEN 'KDF2'
                        WHEN MACHINE = 'KDF01'
                        THEN 'KDF1'
                        END



FROM ( SELECT * FROM [xxx].[xxx].[PARAMETER]
            WHERE ID  = 5) AS Parm 

INNER JOIN 

     (SELECT * FROM [xxx].[xxx].[PHYSICAL_DATA]

            WHERE  MACHINE IN (@Equipment)
             and PARAMETER = 5   ) AS Phys
            ON Parm.ID =  Phys.PARAMETER

            WHERE PARAMETER = 5  
            order by DATETIME desc
```

Comment: Нужно, значит, менять список в репорте, или привязывать к каждому его элементу правильный value.

Comment: в репорте нет возможности сменить имя, т.к на на этом выпадающем меню завязаны еще несколько графиков

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHERE REPLACE(MACHINE, 'KDF0', 'KDF') IN (@Equipment)` ?